# '@user-name' must change when any user changes his\her username

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-replies

All of us can reply to a comment made by any user using `@user-name` and notify them. But I've noticed that this does not change when any user changes his\her username.

Example:

User 'A' posted a comment.

User 'B' replied `@A ,ok.`

When User 'A' changes his username to some other name,the `@A` does not change. If User 'A' changes his\her name to 'C',then the comment should also change to `@C ,ok.`.

I've noticed that this is not implemented by looking at [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers/3959723#comment4232755_3959723) made by a user. It seems that [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308801/a2b?tab=summary) who posted the comment in the above link changed his\her username from 'Green' to 'A2B' but the comment that other user replied wasn't changed.

So why not make this a feature?

Comment: I guess that would be very server intensitive and not really useful at all.. As you can understand the context of such a conversation most of the times.

Comment: and I ofcourse meant intensive instead of intensitive ;)

Comment: I think you're being intesensitive, @Kevin

Comment: @KevinVoorn On a properly [normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies), this shouldn't be any more intensive than the update to username itself. But, if the initial design decisions were made such that the username will not be changed (along with profile updates) it is altogether a different story!

Comment: Updating the username is something entirely different then changing usernames in content, isn't it? While updating the username only requires you to lookup the ID and change the name, changing the name in content would require a script to go over all comments and search for the username. By the looks of it, this is far more intensive. @jjk_charles

Comment: @KevinVoorn what if the comments are designed to store the ID (or any other key that is unique to the @ User) rather than the Name, and dynamically fetch Name from the User table when the comment is being displayed?

Comment: @jjk_charles Might be possible, I'm not really sure how they designed their database structure.

Comment: @KevinVoorn Exactly my doubt too, that is what I mentioned in my initial comment too!

Comment: @jjk_charles Yea, I haven't really thought about your alternative, however I still think it wouldn't be that useful anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @user reply is there to notify the user that they got a message. The *content* of the comments are all that really matters to later readers, so following the converstation isn't really that difficult. Whether the conversation as between @A and @B, or @C and @B doesn't really matter.

Comment: And if it does matter, perhaps that conversation should have been had in chat?

Comment: I have to disagree as finding older posts with mis-labeled comments can be quite confusing, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26269553/3576984). Given the proliferation of deleted comments as posts age, it's hard to tell whether a commenter is referring to a post that no longer exists when they're actually just referring to the above commenter by another name.

Comment: @MichaelChirico See George's comment above. If it matters who a comment was said to, then what's the content really worth to later readers? They should probably just be cleaned up.